# JS Prototype use a class within a class

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
<td class="a-right">
  <span class="price-excl-tax">
    <span class="price">$299.00</span>
  </span>
  <br>
</td>
```

I have the above code in HTML being generated.  I need to use JS Prototype to get the value of the inner span.  There are multiple spans with the class of "price", but only this one is nested inside of the class "price-excl-tax".

http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/Prototype/Selector/

this is what I have:

```
console.log("Base price is: " + $$('price-excl-tax')[0].$$(span.price[0]).value);
```

Comment: You need `.` at the beginning of a class name. You should be able to use `$$('.price-excl-tax .price')` to match a class inside a class. Just like CSS selectors.

Comment: This is essentially a CSS question about [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) or [child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) selectors, has very little to do with JavaScript.

Comment: I disagree it has little to do with javascript.  Normally I would say select by class or ID.  In this particular style it does not have so adding the . to indicate class would make sense.  Thanks to Barmar I am now aware of this instead of assuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Barmar mentioned, use [$$()](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) with a CSS [Child Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (though a basic [Descendant Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) would work as well) like `'.price-excl-tax > .price'`.

See this illustrated in the example below. Note that it utilizes [Event.observe()](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/) for the [*dom:loaded*](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/) event (unique to PrototypeJS) to ensure the DOM is loaded before querying it. Also note that the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property is used to get the contents of the price element, though [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) could also be used if there are no nested HTML nodes.

```js
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  var priceContainers = $$('.price-excl-tax > .price');
  if (priceContainers.length) { //Greater than 0
    console.log("Base price is: " + priceContainers[0].innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a-right">
      <span class="price-excl-tax">
    <span class="price">$299.00</span>
      </span>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

An alternate approach would be to use [Element.select()](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/select/). Something like:

```
var priceExclTaxContainers = $$('.price-excl-tax');
if (priceExclTaxContainers.length) { //not empty
    var priceContainers = priceExclTaxContainers.select('.price');
    if (priceContainers.length) {
          //utilize priceContainers[0].innerHTML
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use child selector. see the below code snipet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="a-right">
  <span class="price-excl-tax">
    <span class="price">$299.00</span>
  </span>
  <br>
</td>
<script>
console.log("Base price is: " + $("price-excl-tax > price"));
</script>
```

Comment: Almost -- the single dollar sign is "Find by ID", and the double-dollar sign is "Find by CSS", and always returns an array of found objects (or an empty array). Try `$$('.price-excl-tax > .price').first()` to get the first one, or iterate over the found collection with `each()`.

Comment: The OP used the tag [PrototypeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototypejs), not jQuery; it is not recommended to include a solution with a different JavaScript library.